# React Native: How do you get a Moneris transaction to return to app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, payment-processing, react-native-webview

I'm processing a transaction with Moneris in my React Native app in a WebView. The URL in my WebView contains the credentials of my Hosted PayPage Configuration as URI parameters. When creating that configuration on the Moneris site, I need to provide the URL for the hosted paypage to redirect to once the transaction is complete. When I enter something like `https://www.google.ca/` as the callback, it works fine, but I don't know what callback URL I'd need to enter to return to my app.

**What I Want To Know:**

What is the callback URL I'd need to use in order to return to a React Native app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebView is just a component inside your app, so you are never leaving your app. First, confirm that page is rendered in a WebView as opposed to launching browser as a separate app and opening a page there (in this case you can't go back to your app programmatically). Then, if you are actually using a WebView component, you could, for example, do the following: add NavigationState listener to your WebView, and read the url the WebView navigates to and take action accordingly

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{

  onNavigationStateChange = (navState) => {
    if (navState.url === 'https://www.yoursite.com') {
      // user just got redirected to requested site
      // do something in react-native app now, for example
      // close this component and show another one
    }
  }

  render(){
    return <View>
      <WebView
      ...
      onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
    />
    </View>
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Max, this is great, thank you. I ended up finding a different workaround, but I think this solves the problem I was originally facing.